# open a file and copy the listed files to another folder

Tags: scripting, find, ksh, cp

I have a file named `file1.txt`containing file names like below :

```
filea.txt
fileb.txt
filec.txt
```

I want to copy the files listed in `file1.txt` to another folder. What is the UNIX command to use? (the shell is `ksh88` if that's relevant).

Comment: Are the file names in file1.txt using full paths? or are all of these files in the same directory?

Answer (score 4):

Your format assumes that no file names have newlines in them, which is not ideal (newlines are legal in filenames). You also don't mention your shell. However, in a POSIX shell, you can do this:

```sh
while IFS= read -r file; do
    cp -- "$file" new_dir/
done < file
```

In bash, it might be faster to pass them all to cp in one go, however (as long as you're below `ARG_MAX`):

```bash
files=()

while IFS= read -r file; do
    files+=( "$file" )
done < file

cp -- "${files[@]}" new_dir/
```

...or, the same thing, if you have bash4+:

```bash
mapfile -t files < file
cp -- "${files[@]}" new_dir/
```

Comment: I typed your lines in a file and execute that file.I think my shell is bash but your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: mapfile -t files <  filecp "${files[@]}" /ettdd/SPECS/tpl/TEMP_TFRW2

Comment: Sorry I meant to say :mapfile -t files <  /ettdd/SPECS/tpl/list_TFRW2.txt
cp "${files[@]}" /ettdd/SPECS/tpl/TEMP_TFRW2

Comment: @Crystal What is the output of `echo "$0"; echo "$BASH_VERSION"`? Try the first example instead, it should work in any POSIX shell. The `mapfile` example will only work on `bash4+`. What error messages are printed?

Comment: I save your first set of codes in a file called cpNmv and execute it. The error is : cpNmv: syntax error at line 5 : `done' unexpected

Comment: I did the echo "$0" and it says /usr/bin/ksh and there is no output when I type "echo "$BASH_VERSION"

Comment: Right, so your shell is `ksh`, not `bash`. Try copying and pasting it -- there's nothing in that code that should cause that.

Comment: Yes, it works using your 1st suggestion! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tools:

```
xargs -rd '\n' cp -t /dest/folder -- < file1.txt
```

POSIXly:

```
sed 's/./\\&/g' < file1.txt | xargs sh -c 'exec cp -- "$@" /dest/dir' sh
```

Comment: For the above suggestion using sed, where should I use file1.txt?